# Undefined reference to std::*something* when linking library staticly

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, g++, c++14

I've compiled some of my code into a static library. Everything from this library begins with Glow or GLOWE prefix. At the moment, I'm testing the library in Linux (Ubuntu 14.04). I made a simple program to check if I did everything correctly.

```
#include <GlowSystem/Package.h>
int main(void)
{
    GLOWE::Package package;

    return 0;
}
```

GLOWE::Package is a class. It uses libzip and zlib (and standard c++ files eg. string). I link both libzip and zlib. When I try to compile, it fails with some linking errors.
[Build log (at pastebin)](https://pastebin.com/FPL7Wm4J)

I thought that these errors are caused by too old libstdc++, but this code compiles:

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    string a;
    a.resize(5000);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm at my wits' end and I have no idea what to do. I will appreciate any help.

Comment: What are g++ flags?

Comment: Looks like you're mixing ABI incompatible code

Comment: @Alex flags are: g++ -Wall -std=c++14 -g -std=c++14 -DGLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -I../GlowE -c /home/thereclif/Pulpit/GlowTest/main.cpp -o obj/Debug/main.o
g++  -o bin/Debug/GlowTest obj/Debug/main.o  -lzip -lz -lstdc++  ../GlowE/GlowEngine/bin/Debug/libGlowEngine.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzip.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your linker options are incorrect:

```
../GlowE/GlowEngine/bin/Debug/libGlowEngine.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzip.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.a
```

Try:

-l../GlowE/GlowEngine/bin/Debug/GlowEngine -l/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/zip -l/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/z

Comment: I checked if it works for me. Unfortunately, it didn't, but it made me look at my build log. It turned out that I compiled my library with -m32, but I didn't compile my program with the same option.